# Grep for Keyword1Keyword2 but not Keyword1TEXTKeyword2 - Very large grep

Tags: bash, grep

I want to be able to grep for exact match results without outputting those with text in between my searched words. the middle being part of the output. For example:

```
egrep -i "^cat|^dog" list.txt >> startswith.txt
egrep -i "home$|house$" startswith.txt >> final.txt
```

I want this to return any matches for cathome, cathouse, doghome, doghouse; but not return cathasahome, catneedsahouse, etc. Take note that the files would be wayyy to big for me to go through and say ^word1word2$ in every combination.

Is there a way to do this within grep or egrep.

Comment: How many words do you need to match?  Because if you are only searching for these 4 (cathome, cathouse, doghome, doghouse), then it's easier to just use `egrep -i "cathome|cathouse|doghome|doghouse" list.txt` and that's all.  Now, if you have a different set of patterns each time, then that's a different story...  Because in your question's title you mention "Very large grep", but if you only have 4 posibilities then I would't consider that a "very large" set of posibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some grouping to specify both parts of your pattern, The anchors (`^` and `$`) will apply to the groups.

```
$ cat list.txt 
cathome
cathouse
catindahouse
dogindahome
doghouse
doghome
$ egrep -i "^(dog|cat)(home|house)$" list.txt 
cathome
cathouse
doghouse
doghome
```

You could try the same thing in Perl regex mode, with non-capturing groups (since you don't care about capturing them):

```
$ grep -Pi "^(?:dog|cat)(?:home|house)$" list.txt
```

No idea if that'll make a difference either way, but doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Seem to be working however not 100% sure if this is the best route for my application. I am literally doing every combination of the words that start with A through words that start with Z and back.

Comment: If you've got hundreds of alternatives then no that doesn't sound like a good idea. You should ask another question with the exact criteria for matching your input.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any sample input or expected output so this is an untested guess but this is probably what you're looking for:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    split("cat dog",beg)
    split("home house",end)
    for (i in beg)
        for (j in end)
            matches[beg[i] end[j]]
}
tolower($0) in matches
' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
acathome
CatHome
catinhouse
CATHOUSE
doghomes
dogHOME
dogathouse
DOGhouse

$ awk '
BEGIN {
    split("cat dog",beg)
    split("home house",end)
    for (i in beg)
        for (j in end)
            matches[beg[i] end[j]]
}
tolower($0) in matches
' file
CatHome
CATHOUSE
dogHOME
DOGhouse
```